# custom delete image within UITabelViewCell only show half of itself

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uitableviewrowaction

I want to custom my delete button of the UITableViewCell like these codes:

```
let deleteAciont = UITableViewRowAction(style: UITableViewRowActionStyle.Normal, title: nil, handler: {action, indexpath in
        do some thing
    });
    deleteAciont.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: UIImage(named: "delete")!)
```

the height of the UITableViewCell is 70 like this:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return 70
}
```

and the images are these size: delete.png:70*70\delete@2x.png:140*140\delete@3x.png:210*210
[image: delete image]

but when i swipe left, the image only show half:
[image]

I have been confusing about this for a long time and thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

the length of the tableViewRowAction will be the title's length

let deleteAciont = UITableViewRowAction(style: UITableViewRowActionStyle.Normal, **title: "     type more space here   "**, handler: {action, indexpath in
        do some thing
    });